# Socket still listening after application crash

Tags: c++, sockets, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm having a problem with one of my C++ applications on Windows 2008x64 (same app runs just fine on Windows 2003x64).

After a crash or even sometimes after a regular shutdown/restart cycle it has a problem using a socket on port 82 it needs to receive commands.

Looking at netstat I see the socket is still in listening state more than 10 minutes after the application stopped (the process is definitely not running anymore).

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:82             LISTENING
```

I tried setting the socket option to REUSEADDR but as far as I know that only affects re-connecting to a port that's in TIME_WAIT state. Either way this change didn't seem to make any difference.

```
int doReuse = 1;
setsockopt(listenFd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
           (const char *)&doReuse, sizeof(doReuse));
```

Any ideas what I can do to solve or at least avoid this problem?

**EDIT:**

Did netstat -an but this is all I am getting:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:82             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

For netstat -anb I get:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:82             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [System]
```

I'm aware of shutting down gracefully, but even if the app crashes for some reason I still need to be able to restart it.  The application in question uses an in-house library that internally uses Windows Sockets API.

**EDIT:**

Apparently there is no solution for this problem, so for development I will go with a proxy / tool to work around it. Thanks for all the suggestions, much appreciated.

Comment: If you have problems even after computer restart it may be some other program using your port. Do a `netstat -anb` to see who's listening on 82.

Comment: This is normal after a crash. The socket inofrmation is held in the OS (your application just holds a handle to the information). When your application crashes (or quits without closing the connection) the socket will remain in use until the OS detects that the listening app has gone (this can sometime be a good 10 minutes). Your best bet is to pass in the port as a command line argument so you can quickly change the port while de-bugging.

Comment: Do you have any error message in the windows event logger ?, maybe Event-ID 4227 ?.

Comment: @Martin: The problem is that the state of the socket remains in state "Listening" forever, even after several hours I cannot restart the app successfully. I also cannot change the port since other applications send the commands to a fixed port (82). Is there no way to re-use the socket? The same app worked just fine on Win 2003.

Comment: This is a problem when developing software. The solution I use (when I can't change the socket). I start a proxy (that works and does not crash) that listens on that socket and forwards any incoming data on 82 to a configurable port. Then you can write your experimental software to use a different port each time you need to switch port. The calling application does not need to know that your application has moved to another port as that is done by reconfiguring the proxy.

Comment: Just FYI: You can use a canned piece of software for the proxy suggested by Martin York if you can find a port of netpipes (http://www.purplefrog.com/~thoth/) for windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is only hurting you at debug time, use [tcpview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) from the sysinternals folks to force the socket closed. I am assuming it works on your platform, but I am not sure.

If you're doing blocking operations on any sockets, do not use an indefinite timeout.  This can cause weird behavior on a multiprocessor machine in my experience.  I'm not sure what Windows server OS it was, but, it was one or two versions previous to 2003 Server.
Instead of an indefinite timeout, use a 30 to 60 second timeout and then just repeat the wait.  This goes for overlapped IO and IOCompletion ports as well, if you're using them.

If this is an app you're shipping for others to use, good luck.  Windows can be a pure bastard when using sockets...

Comment: I was able to use tcpview to close a connected socket for a non-existent process, but not a listening socket.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried setting the socket option to
>   REUSEADDR but as far as I know that
>   only affects re-connecting to a port
>   that's in TIME_WAIT state.

That's not quite correct. It will let you re-use a port in TIME_WAIT state for any purpose, i.e. listen or connect. But I agree it won't help with this. I'm surprised by the comment about the OS taking 10 minutes to detect the crashed listener. It should clean up all resources as soon as the process ends, other than ports in the TIME_WAIT state.

Comment: actually the system never recovers, even after hours the port is unusable, basically only rebooting fixes the problem at that point - this wasn't the case for Win 2003x64 so something in this regard must have changed with Win 2008

Comment: It's an OS bug then. Report it to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is that it really is your application listening on that port. Use:

`netstat -anb`

to figure out which process is listenin on that port.

The second thing to check is that your are closing the socket gracefully when your application shuts down. If you're using a high-level socket API that shouldn't be too much of an issue (you *are* using a socket API, right?).

Finally, how is your application structured? Is it threaded? Does it launch other processes? How do you know that your application is really shut down?

Comment: added clarification + netstat -anb output, also I checked with task manager, the app process is definitely gone, and it doesn't spawn any other processes.

Answer (score 0):

Run

netstat -ano

This will give you the PID of the process that has the port open. Check that process from the task manager. Make sure you have "list processes from all users" is checked.

Comment: I am betting "System" is keeping it open, but I may be wrong.

Comment: That is an indication some windows service is keeping it open, may be a service that was started by your app, indirectly. I would suggest that you shut down running services one by one, and see if the port is freed (or at least went into time_wait state). If, so, you may want to disable that service altogether. Please post your findings.

Answer (score 0):

[http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/addrinuse.html](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/%7Efine/Tech/addrinuse.html) is a great resource for "Bind: Address Already in Use" errors.

Some extracts:

> TIME_WAIT is the state that typically ties up the port for several minutes after the process has completed. The length of the associated timeout varies on different operating systems, and may be dynamic on some operating systems, however typical values are in the range of one to four minutes.
>
> **Strategies for Avoidance**
>
> **SO_REUSEADDR**
>
> This is the both the simplest and the most effective option for reducing the "address already in use" error.
>
> **Client Closes First**
>
> TIME_WAIT can be avoided if the remote end initiates the closure. So the server can avoid problems by letting the client close first.
>
> **Reduce Timeout**
>
> If (for whatever reason) neither of these options works for you, it may also be possible to shorten the timeout associated with TIME_WAIT.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing https://superuser.com/a/453827/56937 I discovered that there was a `WerFault` process that was suspended.

It must have inherited the sockets from the non-existent process because killing it freed up my listening ports.