# Changing Socket Options on WCF net.tcp binding

Tags: wcf, sockets, .net-4.0, tcp

I have a .net 4.0 WCF application that uses the net.tcp binding and implements some service.
I would like to set a TCP socket option for that binding (`ReuseAddress` option. A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12366947/619493) explains why I want to do that).
If I was working with Raw Sockets I could use the [Socket.SetSocketOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.setsocketoption%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Method.

Is there a way to somehow extract the underlying Raw Socket from the net.tcp binding in order to change its options? Or some other way to set this option?

Comment: Try creating a socket with reuse address set & then initialize the net.tcp binding application

Comment: Have you tried net.tcp port sharing?

Answer (score 0):

Amir, Thank you for your suggestion of adding ReuseAddress option. However, we need understand better what was your concrete scenario. In the related question ([Changing Socket Options on WCF net.tcp binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371768/changing-socket-options-on-wcf-net-tcp-binding)) context, have you enable port sharing? Seems like porting sharing could result with similar symptom. Basically, we need concrete repro program and setup steps to understand better of the problem.
If anyone still runs into the problem or see the need of adding reuseAddress option, please report the bug at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio with repro program and repro steps. Thank you.

Comment: This isn't really an answer. Please wait until you're able to comment.

Comment: As you can see, the question is from 2012, almost 4 years ago. By then, after having many issues with WCF (this one among them), I reverted to using sockets directly. btw one major problem was WCF performance, so even if the above problem is resolved, I still prefer using sockets.